# Include SAS files from remote server

Tags: sas

I want to include some files from our remote server and use them on my local machine. Usually I use something like this to include files which are on my pc:

```
%include 'C:\Users\sasfile.sas';
```

Lets say that this file sasfile.sas is on a remote server. How can I access it from my local machine?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: If you need to access it via a non-windows method, such as FTP, you can likely accomplish that with a .bat program and/or scripting.  If you give more information as to how you would access the file yourself (say, you wanted to edit it on your local machine), we could give a more clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by `remote server`.  If you mean a shared folder on another Windows machine (and you have permission to read it), you can just use a network file reference:

```
%include '\\server-name\share-name\folder\sasfile.sas';
```

Answer (score 1):

If by remote server, you mean a remote SAS server to which you're connected from your local client...

```
rsubmit ;
  proc download infile="/path/to/remote/sasfile.sas" outfile="c:\users\sasfile.sas" ;
  run ;
endrsubmit ;
%inc "c:\users\sasfile.sas" ;
```